# Dilation in Lp space

Tags: real-analysis

What does it that mean?
I can't find a reference.

Context is proving Young's inequality.

The context is question 2 in the following link:
http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/MAT1001/D7.pdf

Comment: I would guess "dilation" is a map $x \mapsto ax$ for some $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

It means: consider the effect of applying the map $T_af (x) = f(ax)$ to all the functions for $a > 0$.  Note $T_a (f*g) = (T_af) * (T_ag)$, and $\|T_af\|_p = a^{-1/p} \|f\|_p$.